# Quorum Development

Tags: quorum

i am looking for in depth development reference for JPM Quorum blockchain, i am not able to find anything other than the basics. If anyone has any good resources please share them with me.

to be more specific i have found the following tutorials and they are quite basic:
https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains

As well to focus more on the privateFor private keys and public keys generations

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what in-depth may mean in your case, but here are some samples, ideas, and places to find help

- Official documentation can be found here: https://docs.goquorum.com. This has a ton of things like config and command line switches, and much more
- https://github.com/bacen/quorum-examples/tree/master/examples/5nodesRTGS -- RTGS (Real-time Gross Setlement) systems are very dependent of a central entity, but this design creates a single point of failure. Backup datacenters can help but do not solve the problem completely as there is no real distributed resiliency when using only backup infrastructures. The distributed consensus nature of the blockchain technology can be used to overcome this central point of failure, but at a great privacy cost as all stored data are fully accessible to all network members by default, and this kind of transparency is not allowed in a real bank interpayment network. Quorum privacy properties were used to overcome this problem when implementing a blockchain RTGS system. This example uses Quorum private and public smart contract communication.
- https://github.com/miguelmartinezinf/consistency-checker -- Consistency-checker enhances trust between parties involved in private smart contracts. This tool acts as an oracle, listening to modifications of a specific private contract on every participant node and publishing the unique state of the contract at every block height on a public contract.
- https://github.com/blk-io/quorum-sample -- This project demonstrates the creation and management of a private token on a Quorum network. Quorum privacy is used, only certain members of the network are privy to the token that has been created. It is written in Java using web3j which is maintained by Web3 Labs.
- https://github.com/M-Bowe/pons & https://github.com/M-Bowe/pons-frontend -- Cross-Chain Trading Bridge written to run over 2 Quorum Chains to safely exchange ERC-20 and ERC-721 assets.
- https://github.com/lyotam/techmarketplace -- Marketplace is an example application running on top of a Quorum network which allows users to bid for and offer 
  virtual hackathon gear for sale in an interactive marketplace. This app is based on what was originally developed for the MLH Localhost Quorum workshop, which demonstrates how to run a simple Ethereum application and how to write a simple Smart Contract that interacts with the Ethereum-based network.
- Our slack is probably the best place to ask questions and seek development advice: http://bit.ly/quorum-slack

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation. Everything you will ever need.

https://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/